# Inline CSS for dynamic background in RoR app not working

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

This works in my CSS file:

```
.blog-title-section {
background: image-url('banner-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
}
```

However I would like to make the background dynamic in my html.erb file, so far I've tried

```
<style>
.blog-title-section { background: image-url('banner-bg.jpg') no-repeat     center center; }
</style>
```

and

```
<div class="blog-title-section", stlye="background: image-url('banner-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center;" >
```

Neither of which are working. When I find something that works I'll replace "banner-bg.jpg" with @blog.image.

Comment: i think you didnot get image

Comment: image-url is a rails-sass helper, and your templates are not being compiled... So, use `url()` and pass it a full url. `background: url(<%= image_url('banner-bg.jpg') %>)`

Answer (score 0):

I think problem on your image path, like if your image have `app/asset/images/banner-bg.jpg`

Then your code will `image-url('assets/banner-bg.jpg')` OR `image-url('/assets/banner-bg.jpg')` OR `image-url('../assets/banner-bg.jpg')` which you need